# What is the polarity of this capacitor?

Tags: capacitor

I have a MAL213836109E3 axial capacitor.  There's a stripe on one side of the capacitor, but it isn't a tantalum capacitor.  Does it indicate + or - in this case?

This is the DigiKey link to it:  https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/vishay-beyschlag-draloric-bc-components/MAL213836109E3/263338

Comment: says electrolytic on the datasheet, so it probably is a polarity mark... Actually looking at it I am not fully certain what it is marking. Hope someone else can give more info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what it says in the datasheet:

[image]

And on page 2 there's

[image]